# Anchoring WPF controls to stick the position on form resize

Tags: wpf

all windows controls has property called anchor by which i can force control to stick on its surface and if anyone re-size form the controls height & width also increase & decrease along with form size.

i asked some one that how to do it in wpf and he said as below
'Docking' in WPF can be done by Setting the HorizontalAllignment and the VerticalAllignment properties of a child control.

'Anchoring' in WPF can be done by setting the Margin on the child and/or the Padding on the container.

unfortunately i am not being able to do so. so here is my sample xaml.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window3" Height="300" Width="515">
<Grid>
    <Label Name="lblName" Content="Enter Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-17,5,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Enter Address" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-17,39,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Enter Company" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-17,68,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,10,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,73,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,42,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

so please do edit ny xaml to achieve what i am looking for....thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach.  It will give you static layout:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="lblName" Content="Enter Name"/>     
  <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Enter Address" />     
  <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Content="Enter Company" />     
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="200"/>     
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="200" />     
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width="200"/> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: what it is? i asked different things. when window re-size the controls also re-size proportionately.

Comment: @Thomas  This should "anchor" the controls to the upper-left corner and they should not resize when the window size changes.  Let me know if you don't get this behavior or I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

I will not write the code for you, but I will tell you what you need to do to learn how to code it properly.

First off, you should learn [what layout controls WPF has](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx#LayoutSystem_PanelsCustom). I would actually recommend reading through [this code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start), which includes a quick visual representation of each layout control and how they work.

Your current XAML is using the `Grid` control incorrectly and the way your current controls are setup, you might as well use a `Canvas`, which is used for static layouts.

If you were to use the `Grid` control correctly by defining `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions`, and assigning your controls to a specific `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column`, you'll get what you want. :)

Comment: big dady answer and he set RowDefinitions & ColumnDefinitions both but it is still not working the way i look for.

Comment: @Thomas Remove the `Width`/`Height` properties so it is allowed to stretch based on the Grid cell's size. You can keep the `Margin` property if you want some space between controls, or use extra Row or Column definitions to make the space between controls.